# How can I be a philosopher

Tags: ethics, history-of-philosophy

In this our age of information, i discover that every one is clamming to be a philosopher because of little experience they have or acquire in school or even by friend. And in this information age things are really getting worsen "as i think in my mind" because the internet that we or i think is to educate us and for purpose of documentation, internet has been flooded by sort of confused information with even more false information. I will love to hear from the expert of how can i be a professional philosopher.

Like what i learned by wiki:

A philosopher is someone who practices philosophy, which involves rational inquiry into areas that are outside of either theological dogma or science. The term "philosopher" comes from the Ancient Greek φιλόσοφος (philosophos) meaning "lover of wisdom". Its origination has been ascribed to the Greek thinker Pythagoras.

In the classical sense, a philosopher was someone who lived according to a certain way of life, focusing on resolving existential questions about the human condition, and not someone who discourses upon theories or comments upon authors. Typically, these particular brands of philosophy are Hellenistic ones and those who most arduously commit themselves to this lifestyle may be considered philosophers.

In a modern sense, a philosopher is an intellectual who has contributed in one or more branches of philosophy, such as aesthetics, ethics, epistemology, logic, metaphysics, social theory, and political philosophy. A philosopher may also be one who worked in the humanities or other sciences which have since split from philosophy proper over the centuries, such as the arts, history, economics, sociology, psychology, linguistics, anthropology, theology, and politics. reference [More](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosopher)

So if Philosopher is all about lover of wisdom, i want to know how i can be a profession philosopher because left to me i don't want to be a part of majority that claim to a philosopher. Any help is welcome

Comment: Can you explain how you picked the tags? Also, can you define "philosopher" for the purpose of your question?

Comment: common, i posted this question for the purpose of my own learn , i don't know why do people quick in down voting questions

Comment: "In a modern sense, a philosopher is an intellectual who has contributed in one or more branches of philosophy, such as aesthetics, ethics, epistemology, logic, metaphysics, social theory, and political philosophy", i.e. to the "common" branches of philosophy. Thus, to be a philosopher you have to study works of eminent philosophers of the past and try to produce your own original contribution to one (or more) of the said branches.

Comment: @Michael There hasn't been a "lay philosopher" since Wittgenstein. So if you *really* want to be a professional philosopher in the modern world, I mean realistically, you need to get a PhD in Philosophy from some legitimate university. To begin with, that is (as getting a blackbelt in some martial art is only the *beginning* of your training in that discipline).

Comment: Professional philosophers get paid to do philosophy.  That's the only difference.

Comment: Step 1 : Read and understand different kind of philosophies (stoics, epicurean, platonian, buddhism, christinaity, objectivism , nihilsm,realism all kinds of isms...)

Step 2: Form your own philosophy and practice it

Step 3 :Document and published your findings. If people buy your work you might be professional philosopher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should survey some important philosophies and get involved with highly critical philosophy discussion. criticism is necessary to find errors. one of the main problems with philosophy is lots of people have a bunch of bullshit ideas and don't realize all the problems with their ideas.

the list of philosophies you take a look at should include Objectivism (Ayn Rand) and Critical Rationalism (Karl Popper) in addition to stuff like artistotle and kant which everyone recommends (i think they're bad, but you decide).

the only very good philosophy discussion forum i'm aware of is https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/fallible-ideas/info

(this is a Q&A site, which is a different structure with advantages and disadvantages. it's fine but it's different than open-ended discussion where people just chat and argue)

Comment: great. FYI the guy above is mistaken (i don't have enough karma yet to reply there). there have been lay philosophers since Wittgenstein. you don't need a PhD to think. Ayn Rand is an example of a more recent philosopher who didn't have a philosophy PhD.

Answer (score 1):

Start going about town ranting and raving like a lunatic while declaiming all authority and you''ll be fine.